# How to configure flink SQL client to submit job with checkpointing enabled?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

What is an example of a flinksql-client config file with checkpointing enabled?

When I submit streaming job through flink sql client, the checkpoint is not enabled.

Answer (score 2):

The checkpointing configuration can not be set in flink sql client config file, but it can be set in the cluster configuration file (flink-conf.yaml).

At a minimum you should configure [`execution.checkpointing.interval`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/deployment/config.html#execution-checkpointing-interval), [`state.backend`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/deployment/config.html#state-backend), and [`state.checkpoints.dir`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/deployment/config.html#state-checkpoints-dir).

Something like this, for example:

```yaml
execution.checkpointing.interval: 10000
state.backend: filesystem
state.checkpoints.dir: file:///tmp/flink-checkpoints-directory
state.savepoints.dir: file:///tmp/flink-savepoints-directory
```

See the configuration docs for [checkpointing](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/deployment/config.html#checkpointing), [fault tolerance](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/deployment/config.html#fault-tolerance), and [state backends](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/deployment/config.html#checkpoints-and-state-backends) for more details.

Comment: Thank David for the quick response.                                                                  
      seems flink-conf.yaml is not carried over. see the jirahttps://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-20932

Comment: will give aboe a try and let you know if it is working or not

Comment: The above is the missing configuration. it all worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see in the docs you should be able to do it from the sql client by setting the properties like this:

```sql
SET 'state.checkpoints.dir' = 'hdfs:///bar/foo/';
SET 'execution.checkpointing.mode' = 'EXACTLY_ONCE';
SET 'execution.checkpointing.interval' = '30min';
SET 'execution.checkpointing.min-pause' = '20min';
SET 'execution.checkpointing.max-concurrent-checkpoints' = '1';
SET 'execution.checkpointing.prefer-checkpoint-for-recovery' = 'true';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can actually pass in an init sql file when calling sql client without having to update the cluster conf.yml

./sql-client

```
 -i,--init <initialization file>            Script file that used to init
                                            the session context. If get
                                            error in execution, the sql
                                            client will exit. Notice it's
                                            not allowed to add query or
                                            insert into the init file.
```

in your file you can then specify

```
SET 'execution.checkpointing.interval' = '1min';
```

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/sqlclient/